# Iterating Carbon date inside loop

Tags: php, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

In my Laravel project I want to create a array of next 7 days dynamically. I have following setup:

```
    $pickup_dates = [];
    $today = Carbon::today();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
      $pickup_dates[] = $today->addDay();
    }
    dd($pickup_dates);
```

But when I use dd to dump data my output as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[1] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[2] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[3] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[4] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[5] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[6] => Carbon\Carbon Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

)
```

As you can see it outputs same date, but I want to date sequence of the next 7 days. What I want to achieve is this:

- 2017-08-03
- 2017-08-04
- 2017-08-05
- 2017-08-06
- 2017-08-07
- 2017-08-08
- 2017-08-09

Can you tell me what is the wrong with this code? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with same Carbon object that's why you are getting out put like that.

Try this

```
$pickup_dates = [];
$today = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $pickup_dates[]=Carbon::parse($today);
      $today = Carbon::parse($today)->addDay()->toDateString();
}
dd($pickup_dates);
```

Out put as
[image]

Comment: Converting the $today variable to a string each iteration is inefficient. I know that the effect will be negligible but you are doing extra work for the same reward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you let carbon know how many days you're adding:

`$pickup_dates[] = $today->addDays($i);`

Or the less eloquent way:

`$today = $today->addDay();
$pickup_dates[] = $today;`

Both of these need to be done inside of your loop.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is getting the same date(2017-08-09) as output instead of date sequence. I edited question for better understanding.

Comment: Running your code on the 8th of Aug will result in the output that you are getting because the $today variable is always the 8th and so adding a day will always give you the 9th. You can either use the example above or reset $today each iteration as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

This is much cleaner:

```
$pickup_dates = [];
for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
  $pickup_dates[] = Carbon::now()->addDays($i);
}
dd($pickup_dates);
```